# How would you define a set of 'fundamental operations' over an object?

Tags: ds.algorithms, semantics, implementation, operational-semantics

I'm writing an implementation for a common array structure.

As you would find already familiar, an array is an ordered data structure that you can transform with different (hopefully self-explained) operations like:

- set object at index
- insert object(s) starting at index i
- remove object(s) starting at index i
- splice
- push
- pop
- shift
- unshift
- clear

And then you could intuitively see that you could just code a set of 'fundamental operations' from where you could construct all the other ones. For instance, you could use **splice** to emulate the behavior of all other operations but you could also use **insert** and **remove** to construct all of them.

My question is, then, how would you define those 'fundamental operations'?

Is **splice** a construct of **insert** and **remove**, therefore **insert** and **remove** being fundamental?

Or are **insert** and **remove** special cases of **splice**, therefore **splice** being the fundamental operation for the whole group?

Is there some theory or field of CS that deals with these things?

*P.S. Sorry if I'm making a lot of mistakes when presenting the question. I don't know about the correct language for this and have never studied this stuff formally. I hope that I explained myself correctly.*

Comment: Whoa a downvote, no feedback... wow

Comment: Have you read the help center?  Would you like to elaborate why you believe this question is on-topic (it is a research-level question about theoretical computer science)?  Also, what makes you believe there will be a unique subset of fundamental operations?  There might be many such subsets.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yeah sure, both subsets could be fundamental, but how do you formally define that an operation is 'fundamental'? Do you know of a site of book that deals with this issues?

Comment: Start with a book about data structures.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I honestly can't see the relationship...

Comment: Well, they'll tell you that there is a difference between a list, an array, a stack, and a queue. So then you'll be less puzzled by the Pythonesque do-it-all-in-one arrays.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard notion of "fundamentalness".  It's not clear that what you are looking for is meaningful or makes any sense.  What is "fundamental" is a matter of perspective; I don't see any reason to privilege **insert** as more fundamental than **splice**, or vice versa.

So, if you need a concept of "fundamental" for some reason, you'll need to define for yourself what you mean by "fundamental".  If you're going to head that path, I would suggest that you start by asking yourself, "Why do you care?"

Personally, I suspect an XY problem.  I suspect you're asking the wrong question, and you should go back and ask yourself why you want to know and what you will do with the answer -- and that might help you identify a more sensible question or a more pragmatic path to achieving your real goals.

Comment: Very sensible answer. Fundamentalism as a purpose in itself is dangerous.

Comment: In your case, 'fundamentalness' of your data structure is defined w.r.t. those features you are trying to achieve.